# Is it possible to script DCOM permissions using built-in Windows Server 2003 tools?

Tags: windows-server-2003, scripting, dcom

Is it possible to script commands using batch commands, VBScript, or anything else?  I need to modify a few DCOM components to grant permissions to local groups.

Answer (score 1):

There's a tool called "dcomperm", which might really be a piece of sample code - a colleague of mine says he found a project for it in the visual studio 6 SDK. It apparently will do what you want, assuming you can find/build it.

See also http://www.myitforum.com/articles/11/view.asp?id=9323

Comment: So, I assume the answer to my question is no, because dcomperm is not a built-in tool.  But I will give it a look.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Little late to the party here (ok, a lot late) but here's a post that may be of interest to you if you're still looking for something:

[**Set remote DCOM permissions programatically?**](http://www.powershellcommunity.org/Forums/tabid/54/aff/1/aft/3647/afv/topic/Default.aspx)

One suggestion in the post is to use psexec and reg files.

Comment: Heh heh... Looks like you're looking for old questions to answer like I am, too.  >smile<